# Magento 2: Api getting product collection using category id

Tags: magento2, api

I am trying to get product collection using Rest Api 
Below is my code
file:  ProductsManagementInterface.php

> interface ProductsManagementInterface {
>
> ```
> /**
>  * GET for Products api
>  * @param string $param
>  * @return array
>  */
> public function getProducts($param); }
> ```

webservice define in xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route method="GET" url="/V1/productcollection/products/:param">
        <service class="Vendor\ProductCollection\Api\ProductsManagementInterface" method="getProducts"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

model file

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\ProductCollection\Model;

class ProductsManagement implements \Vendor\ProductCollection\Api\ProductsManagementInterface
{

    protected $_categoryFactory;
    protected $_category;
    protected $_categoryRepository;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $jsonHelper;

    public function __constructor(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $category,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
    Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ){
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_category = $category;
        $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    /**
     * Return mixed.
     *
     * @api
     * @param string $param.
     * @return array.
     */
    public function getProducts($param)
    {
        $json = $this->getJsonArrayProductFromCategory($param);
        $decodedData = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($json);
        return $decodedData;
        //return 'hello api GET return the $param ' . $param;
    }

    public function getJsonArrayProductFromCategory($id){
        $category =  $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($id);
        $categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $json= array();
        $i=0;

        foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) 
        {
                $productData['sku'] = $product->getSku();
                $productData['name'] = $product->getName();
                $productData['price'] = $product->getPrice();
                $productData['url'] = $product->getProductUrl();
                $json[$i]=$productData;
                $i++;
        }
        return $json; 
    }
}
```

My url is

http://domian.com/rest/V1/productcollection/products/5

but it give 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code first one is you define the wrong `__constructor`

Change your `__constructor` to `__construct` like,

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $category,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ){
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        $this->_category = $category;
        $this->_categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
```

and run the `di:compile` from your Magento 2 root command line,

`php bin/magento setup:di:compile`

and the second problem is you are passing the Array instead of string to this line,

```
    $decodedData = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($json);
```

I am not sure what kind of output format you want but to check if it's working for you can remove this like and just return `$json` like this,

```
    /**
     * Return mixed.
     *
     * @api
     * @param integer $param.
     * @return array.
     */
    public function getProducts($param)
    {
        $json = $this->getJsonArrayProductFromCategory($param);
        return $json;
    }
```